# How to force URL decode before katharsis tries to parse the filter parameters? %5B %5D

Tags: java, spring, ember-data

I am using katharsis 2.0.0 to build a JSON:API based service. This is being done within spring-boot 1.3.0 for use with Ember 2.0 (ember-data).  Ember properly formats the filter parameters as:

> /resource/filter[id]=xxxx

And URL encodes it properly as:

> /resource/filter%5Bid%5d=xxxxx

However, katharsis complains that it's not formatted properly and is not URL decoding the parameters.  Is there any way to either:

1. URL decode URL in request before it get's to katharsis
2. Get ember-data to not url-encode the [ and ] characters?

I believe this may actually be a bug in katharsis but need a work-around.

Answer (score 0):

It was considered a bug and should be fixed. Work-around is to extend the ServletKatharsisInvokerFilter with one that overrides the getRequestQueryString method with one that does the URLDecoder.decode. Then create a JsonApiFilter that extends AbstractKatharsisFilter as a Component (BeanFactoryAware) and override the createKatharsisInvokerContext to use the new invoker filter.

katharsis-servlet and katharsis-spring v2.0.3 has been released with fixed query parameters.

https://github.com/katharsis-project/katharsis-core/issues/167